# WebStorm: JavaScript code-complete for dynamically generated class methods

Tags: javascript, webstorm, code-completion, dynamic-properties

How to annotate a dynamically generated class method in WebStorm so it shows up in the autocomplete?

So far I was able to accomplish similar thing for properties:

```
/**
 * @property prop1
 * @property prop2
 */

class MyClass{
    //empty class
}
```

Now if I type `new MyClass().pr` then WebStorm shows both `prop1` and `prop2` in the code completion popup.

What is the correct syntax for methods?

It seems [@name](https://jsdoc.app/tags-name.html) should do the trick, but WebStorm doesn't recognize it for autocompletion.

Or maybe it's not about annotations but there is a different way of accomplishing that?

Any IDEas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not using `@property` for this? Like:

```
/**
 * @property prop1
 * @property prop2
 * @property {function(string)} method1
 */

class MyClass{}
```